# Random Server shutdown? - CentOS

Tags: linux

My system was working fine, and then it just had a random restart.

Anyone have any idea of the problem?

The message log:

```
Jul  6 22:56:34 909I7 shutdown[719711]: shutting down for system halt
Jul  6 22:56:34 909I7 init: Switching to runlevel: 0
Jul  6 22:56:35 909I7 smartd[10743]: smartd received signal 15: Terminated
Jul  6 22:56:35 909I7 smartd[10743]: smartd is exiting (exit status 0)
Jul  6 22:56:42 909I7 hcid[8749]: Got disconnected from the system message bus
Jul  6 22:56:42 909I7 auditd[8430]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Jul  6 22:56:42 909I7 kernel: audit(1341640602.922:344412): audit_pid=0 old=8430 by auid$
Jul  6 22:56:43 909I7 pcscd: pcscdaemon.c:572:signal_trap() Preparing for suicide
Jul  6 22:56:43 909I7 pcscd: hotplug_libusb.c:376:HPRescanUsbBus() Hotplug stopped
Jul  6 22:56:44 909I7 pcscd: readerfactory.c:1379:RFCleanupReaders() entering cleaning f$
Jul  6 22:56:44 909I7 pcscd: pcscdaemon.c:532:at_exit() cleaning /var/run
Jul  6 22:56:44 909I7 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Jul  6 22:56:44 909I7 kernel: Kernel log daemon terminating.
Jul  6 22:56:45 909I7 exiting on signal 15
```

Comment: YOu need to go back a bit further before the system halt was sent. check /var/log/messages (possibly older than what you have pasted) /var/log/secure . It is possible a halt command was sent by application or by user.

Comment: This log is not enough to give any reasonable guess what may have gone wrong. Show more of the log and see if some of the other logs contain any relevant messages. May be there was a scheduled shutdown pending? Check your /var/log/cron/* or similar.

Comment: Grep for any acpi events.

Comment: I am running the OpenVZ kernel on this Machine, and it was really odd to see it crash randomly. I had the Datacenter Techs check the machine when it went down, and oddly enough there was no response on the machine period when they went to check on it. I am hoping i am able to find the cause of this, as it does not look like the logs are showing me anything of importance.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a clean shutdown. Someone issued the shutdown command or pressed the server power button, which then issued an ACPI shutdown. There's nothing more we can tell you from that snippet.

Take a look at auth.log and see if someone was logged in at your server around that time.

Comment: I am running the OpenVZ kernel on this Machine, and it was really odd to see it crash randomly. I had the Datacenter Techs check the machine when it went down, and oddly enough there was no response on the machine period when they went to check on it. I am hoping i am able to find the cause of this, as it does not look like the logs are showing me anything of importance.

Answer (score -1):

just type  "last reboot" and check , how may times the server rebooted....

Then just go and change the front bazel of the blade server. Which has the USB connector socket. This the server will work fine and no reboots.